# Find the number of integer pairs $x,y$ between $0$ and $100$ such that $x^{20}$ has the same remainder as $y^{50}$ when divided by $101$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How would I even do such a problem(without a calculator are anything like that)? I really don't have any idea on where to start for this problem. I know the answer is $1001$ from the [code](https://repl.it/@xxxx/Math-prob) that I made to solve this problem. It might be worth noting that the integer pairs that produced equal remainders all produced remainders of $1$ except for $x=y=0$, which produced a remainder of $0$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* $\mathbb Z_{101}^\times$ is a cyclic group of order $100$. If $x^{20} \equiv z \equiv y^{50} \bmod 101$, then $z^5 \equiv 1$ and $z^2 \equiv 1$. Therefore, $z \equiv 1$. If $d$ divides $100$, then there are exactly $d$ solutions for $t^d \equiv 1 \bmod 101$.